# Termination for failed background verification

Tags: software-development, india, software

I started working at one of the MNC company 8 months ago. They have sent me a message saying my background verification has failed, so they are terminating my employment.

They will provide only a service letter. They have not provided a relieving letter.

I don't know what to do next. I don't even know if I can list this job on my resume. Can I?

Comment: Feb 26th joining and received probation completed  mail after 6months.. in this nov i received termination mail

Comment: Given you mention a "relieving letter", are you working in India?

Comment: Why are you disclosing the name of the employer? Is it relevant to the question?

Comment: Fine for what? Fine for your next employer? We have no idea what you next employer is going to find suitable. What is most likely is they will want to understand exactly who you worked for for 8 months, and they'll want to see the service letter. They will almost certainly ask why you are no longer employed.

Comment: I will add my 8 months exp .. it is fine ?

Comment: @Ram why have you deleted your comment saying that you put a year of fake experience on your resume?

Comment: I am aware of this site .. if I ask my doubt to be open any one can will give proper answer ?

Comment: Yes .. am in add 1year fake experience that the reason i believe that mnc company termination me .. now i can remove that fake experience .. so now i have 3  years experience can add this 8 months or not that's my doubt ? No issue for adding ?

Comment: The MNC company provides only service letter and payslips it enough for join in new organisation?

Comment: You were absolutely employed for 8 months. The answer that says you were not is just wrong.

Comment: Yes , am working 8 months .. and i have 8 months pay slips

Answer (score 4):

Next potential employer will see the gap in your resume on 8 months and ask what you were doing.

So, you will need to include your experience with that MNC.

You don't want to be in a position where you are in an interview and considering lying about what you've been doing. Lies tend to get uncovered.

Best thing you can do is put it in your resume.

Comment: I don't have reliving letter can go with service letter ?

Comment: My understanding that either achieves the same purpose. Hopefully someone with better knowledge of Indian employment can comment.

Comment: "Lies tend to get uncovered" and from a comment "Am add one year fake experience that the reason". Oh, how right you are.

Comment: Yes.. that's  why now taking clarity

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends. You need to take into account why you failed the background check.

- In case the check was failed because of something currently beyond your control (ex: past criminal record) - then it is okay. This is likely to be there forever, you cannot undo it. Next time, before joining make sure that the specific case is not a deal breaker for your next position / opportunity.
- However, in case the check failed because you deliberately provided wrong information, then it's problematic.

If it's the former - then you can go ahead and list the experience. If any follow-up questions are there, you can answer truthfully.

However, if it's the later, I don't think you really had a "service", so you should not claim the experience. It just took them weirdly long time to figure out your lie, but in effect, you never had an engagement with them in professional capacity. I'd advise to leave it out of your next resume.

Comment: I really don't understand how you can say they never had an engagement with them in a professional capacity. Presumably the OP was spending time working on things for the company, and got pay cheques from the company and got experience with whatever the company does. The employment was indeed started, and was then terminated on the basis of a process coming to a conclusion.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Well, IANAL, but as I see the employment contract(s) in India, it mentions that the background check is a **pre-requisite** for the employment contract. Unfortunately it took very long for the company to find out the lack of eligibility, but as per the usual norms, it nullifies any contract, and the employee is not considered to receive any benefits from the employment. I guess work experience is valid only when we have a valid work agreement.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie See this recent article: https://www.outlookindia.com/business/accenture-india-fires-employees-with-fake-documents-report-news-235398 . I'm not saying this is the case for the OP, but if it is, they're lucky that charges are not pressed.

Comment: If what you are saying is true, then people in India can work two jobs at the same time by just having pending background check with one of them. If the employee started work, they were employed, regardless of what is written on a piece of paper.

Comment: The article said they were fired. Which means they were employed?

Comment: @GregoryCurrie Well, usually that piece of paper and what's written on it is admissible in a court, so I guess it has it's merit. Rest, IANAL.

Comment: If the OP goes to court and is bluntly asked "Did you do work for Accenture?" and answers "Yes", and Accenture is asked the same question, and answers "Yes", and the bank records show Accenture paying the OP, I don't think anyone would take that piece of paper seriously.

Comment: @Ram - I will be honest, I don't know the inner workings of how references work in India, but if it's anything like the rest of the world the minute a future employer asks about your employment on the company in question it will come out you were terminated for cause.  However, you will have to explain the alernative, of having a 8 month unexplained gap in your employement record on your resume.  So neither option is a good option.